# Software Updater & Software Center not working

Tags: updates, software-center

Running the update command gives this error message.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Type '�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������ռ��ռ��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

What does this mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you check the first line of your source list file as the message clearly says?

Comment: How do I do that? I am a NOOB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like something has splurged binary nonsense into something that should be a text file. There isn't a simple way to step around this, you need to fix the file.

Check the file first. If it's just the first line that's like this, delete the line, save and try again:

```
sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Failing that, I would look at deleting (`sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list`) and [regenerating a new sources.list](https://askubuntu.com/q/124017/449). It's easiest to just use the Software Properties GUI but the [RepoGen website](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) is fairly useful if you want to add a load of other repos at the same time.

Comment: Thanks your solution of restoring the default repositories helped a lot. ( http://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories )

Answer (score 0):

Your  /etc/apt/sources.list file is corrupt. Try `mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak` and restore an uncorrupted version from your backup or copy an unmodified one from installation media.